# How to access a variable of a function from an another function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope

I need a help with codeigniter, I have in controller in  public function `index()` this

```
$data['book'] = $this->db->query(*something*)->result();
```

and it's normally working but when I want to use it in other function. for example in `public function bookshelf()` it wrote me  **"variable $data seems to be unused in it's scope"** and it's not working

How do I use `$data` from `bookshelf()` function ?

edit: It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

When setting and getting, Use with `$this`

```
$this->data['book'] = $this->db->query(*something*)->result();
```

Comment: <?php foreach ($book as $bookshelf) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $knihovny->jmeno; ?></td>
            <td><?= $knihovny->prijmeni; ?></td>
            <td><?= $knihovny->registrace; ?></td>
            <td><?= $knihovny->bydliste; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
I need variable because of this.

Comment: I just paste that code with foreach  bad.. in my project it's okey and it works.. but only in index function

Answer (score 0):

create a search function

```
public function Search ($query){
        return $this->db->query($query)->result();
    }
```

use it anywhere

```
public function index(){
        $data['search'] = $this -> Search ("%query%");
    }
```